# Pipe and filter bash outputs in realtime

Tags: bash, awk, grep, pipe, ffmpeg

I am running some commands in bash (basically some `ffmpeg` commands), that I'm using `grep` and `awk` to filter out the results. The command takes some time and continously outputs some results as it progresses through the video. The `grep` pipe is the same. But the `awk` pipe waits until the command is completed and prints all at once, which is not good. I want it to output **as soon as** it found a match.

How to change this command to output results in real-time as it progresses?

```
ffmpeg -i freeze.mp4 -vf "freezedetect=n=-60dB:d=2" -map 0:v:0 -f null - 2>&1 | grep freezedetect | awk '{print $4,$5}' | tr -d , | grep lavfi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With standard tools, try

```
ffmpeg -i freeze.mp4 -vf "freezedetect=n=-60dB:d=2" -map 0:v:0 -f null - 2>&1 |  stdbuf -o 0 grep freezedetect | stdbuf -o 0 awk '{print $4,$5}' | stdbuf -o 0 tr -d , | stdbuf -o 0 grep lavfi
```

Comment: This one still prints all at once!

Comment: You may want to add stdbuf to all the following commands as well

Comment: Yes. Adding `stdbuf -o 0` to all pipes does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

`expect` provides a tool, `unbuffer`, which you can use to solve this.  It will connect to your long-running `ffmpeg` process with a pseudoterminal, which makes the system act as though it's interactive rather than using the 4K buffer that pipelines usually incorporate:

```
$ unbuffer ffmpeg [...] | grep [...] | awk [...]
```

Further, you can combine the `grep` and `awk` into one operation:

Rather than:

```
[...] | grep freezedetect | awk '{print $4,$5}' | tr -d , | grep lavfi
```

Instead, you can:

```
[...] | awk '/freezedetect/ && ( $4 /lavfi/ || $5 /lavfi/ ) {print $4,$5}' | tr -d ,
```

Comment: how to get unbuffer? Standard tools would be better.

Comment: `unbuffer` comes with `expect`.  I agree that standard tools, all things being equal, are better; I hadn't recalled that `grep` came with `--line-buffered`.